# Is it possible to make a link from file A to file B in a different directory within the same SVN repository?

Tags: linux, svn, symlink

Within the same SVN repository, I have two directories, `backend/` and `product/`, both containing a file named `test.xml`.

How can I make a link from `product/test.xml` to `backend/test.xml`, such that after I have modified the file `product/test.xml` and done an `SVN commit`, I would get the modified `test.xml` by doing an `SVN up backend/test.xml`?

By the way, it seems SVN Externals don't work, or have I used it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `svn externals` to achieve what you want ([SVN 1.6+](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html), about two-thirds of the way down).

First, you will need to `svn delete` test.xml from the `backend\` folder and `svn commit`. Then, in the `backend\` folder, you can set your external thus:

`me@computer:/backend$ svn propset svn:externals "^/Projects/SomeProject/product/test.xml test.xml" .`

(Information about the special `^` (caret) character here in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294256/favorite-non-obvious-feature-of-svn#3094369)).

It's worth noting that this will overwrite the previous value of the `svn:externals` property on that path. If you need to set multiple externals, save a text file of these (named, say, `svn.externals`) in the format:

```
(path01) (name01)
(path02) (name02)
(path03) (name03)
.
.
.
(pathN) (nameN)
```

and use the -F switch, like so:

`svn propset svn:externals -F svn.externals .`

You could do this more easily with a GUI client like [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/).

Hope this helps.